# Multiple variable assignment in a command

Tags: bash

I have a function that outputs on stdout as well as on stderr. E.g.

```
function test(){
   echo "out"
   echo "err" >&2
}
```

Now, calling this function, who can I redirect both output pipes to different bash variables? So it should work as the following line

```
f=`tempfile`
x=`test 2>"$f"`
y=`cat "$f"`
```

but without having to redirect on pipe into a file. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: No, you can't. (See process substitution if you just need to pipe the streams separately.)

Comment: Horrible hack at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002#line-96